# myForm.$valid returns true even though required feld is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-required

I have a form `myForm` with some input fields.

What am I trying to implement: Each field is `required` only if at least one of the others input fields is not empty.

How I do it: I set `ng-required="ctrl.isAtLeasOneFieldSet()"` on each field. This function check to see if any field is set.
Until here it works. If I set a field it returns `true` and if no field is set it returns `false`. I see it also in the "developer-console-inspector" in Firefox, required changes between true and false when I set and unset a value in one of the input fields.

What doesn't works: I habe a submit function in my controller:

```
function submitForm(valid) {
   if(!valid) {
      return;
   }
}
```

And on the form `ng-submit="ctrl.submitForm(ctrl.myForm.$valid)"`.
Even though the `ng-required` is set to `true` and the input field is not set, the `valid` in `submitForm` returns `true`.
I have used this technique thousand times with `ng-required="someValue"` but not with a functionl like now and it works fine. I think there is a problem when I set `ng-required` with `ctrl.isAtLeasOneFieldSet()`. It looks as the form will not get the update to `required`.

Here a simulation:

> index.html - form

```
<form name="ctrl.myForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" data-ng-submit="ctrl.submitForm(ctrl.myForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        <input name="name"
            data-ng-model="data.name"
            data-ng-required="{{ctrl.isAtLeasOneFieldSet()}}"
        />
        <input name="surname"
            data-ng-model="data.surname"
            data-ng-required="{{ctrl.isAtLeasOneFieldSet()}}"
        />
        <!---->
</form>
```

> index.js - submitForm()

```
function submitForm(valid) {
    if(!valid) {
        return;
    }

    // Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in this case. Though I am not sure what is the difference.

right:  `data-ng-required="ctrl.isAtLeasOneFieldSet()"`

wrong:   `data-ng-required="{{ctrl.isAtLeasOneFieldSet()}}"`

If someone knows why it behaves like that and what exactly happens in each case, please write the answer here.

Comment: `required` is and html directive so to pass a value you need to evaluating that with angularjs expersion `required="{{value == 5}}"`. The other way, `ng-required` is an angularjs directive and all content with be evaluated as expresion, so you don't need to use the extra interplation `{{}}`, for that is fine `ng-required="value == 5"`